# Doing random function in random interval (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do a random function in random time interval.
Here's code:

```
    function numberOne() {
          $("#here").hmtl("numberOne");
        }

        function numberTwo() {
          $("#here").hmtl("numberTWO");
    }

    var randomfunction = [numberOne, numberTWO]
    var randomfunction = randomfunction[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomfunction.length)];


    (function loop() {
      var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 500)) + 500;
      setTimeout(function() {
        randomfunction();
        loop();
      }, rand);
    }());
```

It doesn't work. I dont know why. Can you help me and explain all mistakes? Thanks!

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* as in "fails to even run", "runs but explodes at some point", "runs but doesn't do what I'd expect", or...?

Comment: I know that there are  .hmtl but this still isn't working! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're checking your console you will find that it raise the following error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: numberTWO is not defined(…)

So your code will work just by fixing this problem, replace :

```
var randomfunction = [numberOne, numberTWO];
```

By :

```
var randomfunction = [numberOne, numberTwo];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong function call I can see, hmtl instead of html.

But I think we can change your approach and take it to the next level. You can do it this way.

```
    function numberOne() {
      $("#here").html("numberOne");
    }

    function numberTwo() {
      $("#here").html("numberTwo");
    }

    var randomFunctionsArray = [numberOne, numberTwo];

    function loop() {

       randomFunctionsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomFunctionsArray.length)]();

       setTimeout(function() {
           var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (1000 - 500)) + 500;
           loop();
       }, rand);

     }

     loop();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(function($){
  function functionOne () {
    console.log('one');
  }
  
  function functionTwo () {
    console.log('two');
  }
  
  var functions = [functionOne, functionTwo];
  
  (function loop () {
    var waitTime = Date.now() % 5000;
    var executionIndex = Date.now() % functions.length;
    console.log(executionIndex);
    console.log(waitTime);
    functions[executionIndex]();
    setTimeout(loop, waitTime);
  })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```